# Java Networking “Connection Refused: Connect”

Tags: java

I am trying to do a basic networking program using sockets
**Server:**

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class Socketserver{
    public static void main(String[]z)throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Server is started");
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9999);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client request");
        Socket s=ss.accept();
        System.out.println("client connected");
        InputStreamReader a=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(a);
        String str=b.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client data"+str);
        String nickname=str.substring(0,3);
        OutputStreamWriter os=new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(os);
        out.write(str);
        os.flush();
        System.out.println("data sent from server to client");
}}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class Socketclient{
    public static void main(String[]z)throws IOException{
        String ip="localhost";// for same machine
        int port=9999;
        Socket s=new Socket(ip,port);
        String str="Rujhaan";
        OutputStreamWriter os=new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(os);
        out.write(str);
        os.flush();
        InputStreamReader a=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(a);
        String nickname=b.readLine();
        System.out.println("data from server"+nickname);
    }
}
```

The program compiles and there is no problem on the server but running client always gives connection refused or connection timed out exception.
I have tried different port names and also there is nor firewall problem.
Please suggest me what to do....

Comment: Your code mostly works for me, i mean there is an issue where the client doesn't write a newline char, but it connects, it doesn't time out.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the function readLine. The Specification says the method read the stream until an new line ("\n") is received

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Change your input string to

```
String str="Rujhaan\n";
```

will works or alternative close the OutputStream on client to terminate data transmission.

```
out.close();
```